# How to assign the value of an index of a list to a variable in Python if you only know the index number and don't know or care about the element

Tags: python-3.x, list, indexing

I just spent 4 hours trying to google the answer asked pretty much as above.  There were 10,000 results on how to find the index of an element.  But I am not interested in any of the elements and never know what they will be, how long they will be, nor what they will contain since the string is user's input.

I have studied the Python manual for "lists" and tried several methods. I used loops of several types. List comprehensions were simply too complicated for my tiny brain although I tried. In fact, I tried for 4 hours googling and tweaking things maybe a hundred times but I only received errors after error of every type which I chased down one by one.  I am not providing any code because I am not interested in having anyone fix it (its for an online course and that would be cheating). I just want to know the syntax for one little thing that is preventing me from making it work.

I need to assign the position of any element (i.e., the index integer value) anywhere in the list to a variable so I can control some boundaries. The most important thing for me is to set some conditions for the first character of the string converted to a list.

I was not very clear explaining what I am trying to do so I edited to add this:

```
 pseudo code:
    1. Ask the user for input and assign it a variable
    2  Convert the string into a list where each letter of the string is an element of the list.
    #The operation is dependent only on the position and not on the content of each character in the list.    
    3  For some elements of the list (but not all of them, which is why a loop won't work) perform an operation depending on  their position (or index value)in the list.

in other words:"if the element is in position 0 of the list (or 3 or 27 etc) of the list then do something to the element." And I won't know or care what the content of the original element was.
```

If I know how to do that then I can extrapolate it for other character positions in the list.

I am an total beginner, and am not familiar with technical jargon, so please provide the simplest, least complex method! :-)  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Without code it's really hard to understand what you are trying to do. Can you come up with a *minimal* example that shows what you are starting with, what you want in as a result, and why?

Comment: If I have a 'list' of characters like [a,b,c] I want to take the index value of the first element of the list (which would be 0) and assign that the value 0 to an integer variable like maybe  x=0 NOT x=a.  Does that help?   I could do that using a loop but I need to be able to do without using a loop because the loop gets in the way for what I ant. I want to be able to do it using an assignment operator or a single statement.

Comment: You are saying you want to take the index value of the first element of the list and assign that the value 0 to a variable. But the index of the first value of a list will *always* be `0`. So, why is simple `x = 0` not what you want?

Comment: I could do that for the first element because that will always be a target.  But I need more than just the position of first element. The position of the others (or even how many) is unknown to me while coding. A function returns determine those values. The function will calculate the other positions (and how many), but I will not know what they are so the function needs to assign the positions to a variable on its own without my manually coding  it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I also tried this one:**
I think this is what you want. It assigns the value of an index (0,1,2,3) of a list to a variable.

```
 list = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"]
 item = input("Enter some text: ")
 if item == list[0]:
     index = 0
 elif item == list[1]:
     index = 1
 elif item == list[2]:
     index = 2
 print(index)
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this will work! with some modification  Wish I had thought of it!  I thought that there might be a simple assignment statement like x=list[y]  but I could not find anything.  That particular attempt just provided the element at that index.

Answer (score 2):

I'm an amateur myself but I will take a shot. If you can please do share some more context and some code for clarity.

I just checked the comment you made 50 mins ago. If I understand correctly, you want to assign the indexes to a variable. If that's correct can use the `enumerate` function. It's a built-in function for sequences. If we were to apply enumerate on our list named `text` it will return the position e.g. the index and the value of that position.

```
text = ["B", "O", "O", "M"]
for index, value in enumerate(text):
    print(index, value)
```

This code will give you the following result:

```
0 B
1 O
2 O
3 M
```

Inside the for loop, you have the `index` variable that will now refer to the position of each value. You can now apply further conditions, like `if index == 0:...` and do your thing.

Does this help?

Comment: Thank you.  But I am not interested in determining the content of the elements of the list. only their positions. Eventually I will test the contents of elements (actually their attributes) within the string to determine the positions that will need an operation performed. But first I have to figure out how to have the program assign a list index to a variable.  That's all I need to know.  I can do everything else myself.

Comment: I just read my previous comment and I realized that the comment might come off as arrogant or unfriendly and I did not want that. But it won't let me edit it.  Please know that I am grateful for your suggestion and taking the time to help.

Comment: Hello! It's absolutely alright! I understand how tough it is when you start learning a new language. Have patience and best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

**I tried this because you said: "if this is index 0 of the list then do this"**

It checks if the value of the input is the item with index 0 of the list.

```
list = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"]
item = input("Enter some text: ")
if item == list[0]:
   print("This is index 0 of the list")
else:
   print("This is not index 0 of the list")
```

If this is not the thing you're looking for, could you please try to explain it in a different way? Or maybe try writting some code too please.